# Can I access a Windows 8 .tlb whilst developing on Windows 7 and using VS 2010?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-8, com, reference

The development platform for our C# project is currently Visual Studio 2010, and my development computer is Windows 7.

I need to implement some code for a Windows interface that is part of Mbnapi.tlb, and is only available on Windows 8.

When I check on my computer, the Windows 8 version of this file is present (see below).
[image]

So, according to help that I got from a previous SO question, I removed the reference to Mbnapi.tlb from my project, and added a reference to C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\lib\win8\um\x64\Mbnapi.tlb.

The problem is, that it doesn't seem to work.  I saved the change, and then tried to access an API function that is only available in Windows 8, and it is not visible.

When I opened the project in VS 2012 on a Windows 8 computer and made the same reference change to the newer Mbnapi.tlb, I was able to see the Windows 8 functionality in Visual Studio.

Because the Windows 8 versions of the .tlbs are available in my development environment, I assume that I ought to be able to use them, even for functionality that can't be tested on Windows 7.

My question is: Does anyone know how to get round this problem, so that I can develop for Windows 8 on a Windows 7 computer?

Comment: The type library is only describing the interface to a COM object. If the COM object doesn't exist in Windows 7 (or has a different interface) then it won't work (as you you've found). It sounds to me like you're confusing the `tlb` with the COM object it describes.

Comment: I am confused about the whole thing.  Why does MS make the .tlb library available on Win7, if there is no COM object behind it?  There is a guide to using Mbnapi for C# projects, but it was published in 2009, and doesn't address this issue.

Comment: It does have a COM object but it is an older one with a different interface - Hans said it right when he suggested generating the interops on the Win8 machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot work, adding a reference to a .tlb file causes Visual Studio to use a `<COMReference>` element in your project file that states the type library {guid}.  Not the file.  You'll inevitably get the registered Win7 version of the type library, not the Win8 version.  So you'll see the Win8 additions missing.  This is a Good Thing, it ensures your program can actually be debugged and tested.

You must instead run [Tlbimp.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the Win8 machine to convert the type library to an interop library.  You'll get MbnApi.dll, copy it to your Win7 machine into your project directory and add a reference to it.

Comment: Ah, thank you for that.  I had found the instructions for running Tlbimp.exe in the white paper from MS, but couldn't join the dots about how to adapt it for this particular case.  I will try Tlbimp.exe tomorrow when I get the Windows 8 computer.